# How to apply inbuilt or custom theme to fragment within an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

My problem is to make a fragment full screen and apply custom theme on it. I tried this way but unable to get result. RssDetailViewFragment.cs consists following lines of code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
        Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(Activity, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeLightNoTitleBarFullScreen);

        // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.CloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

        rootView = localInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RSSFeedDetails, null, false);


        // inflate progressbar
        progressBar = rootView.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        // setting control toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = rootView.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.top_control_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)this.Activity).SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // setting icon on toolbar            
        toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_back20);
        toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.primary));

        View navigationIcon = toolbar.GetChildAt(1); //NavigationIcon
```

and my xml file for RssFeedDetals is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/viewBackground">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/top_control_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/TopControlToolbar" />            
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/viewBackground">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main thing to ask this question is to make the fragment fullscreen on Min Sdk 15 plus.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to hide the `StatusBar` ?

Comment: @ York Shen In fact I want to hide the toolbar of activity and statusBar of app and cover the area with fragment view.

Comment: When you show your `RssDetailViewFragment` you could hide the toolbar like this : `FragmentTransaction ft = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();` `RssDetailViewFragment mg = new RssDetailViewFragment();` `ft.Replace(Resource.Id.ll, mg);`
`toolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;`

Comment: In your  `RssDetailViewFragment`, you could hide the `Statusbar` like this :  `WindowManagerLayoutParams attr = Activity.Window.Attributes; attr.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen; Activity.Window.Attributes = attr;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @York Shen, I was able to hide the status bar with your code but toolbar I wanna hide is from Activity's one but not fragment's one. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I understand what you means, this `toolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone`  is called in your `Activity`.  When you switch to the `RssDetailViewFragment ` in your `Activity`, at the same time, you calling `toolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone` to hide your `toolbar`.

Comment: But I switch to RssDetailViewFragment from RssListFragment not from activity.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149146/discussion-between-ishwor-khanal-and-york-shen).

Comment: I have sent there in chatroom.

Comment: Not yet, I wonder you applied toolbar visibility for activity in your last code but I want to hide activity's tool bar how can I access this from RssDetailViewFragment.cs?

Comment: Write these code : `ftoolbar = (V7Toolbar)Activity.FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar); 
ftoolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; ` in your `RssDetailViewFragment` the toolbar you hide is from Activity.

Comment: Finally, done !!! Thank you so much York Shen for your effort and time. I did the same way as you explained and it did work.  // hide the toolbar of activity
            var activityToolbar= (this.Activity).FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.testToolbar);
            activityToolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

Comment: How to mark as an answer can you please tell me . I will do that.

Comment: Of course, I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to hide the toolbar of activity and statusBar of app and cover the area with fragment view.

When you show your `RssDetailViewFragment` you could hide the `Statusbar` and `Toolbar` like this :

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //Hide the StatusBar
        WindowManagerLayoutParams attr = Activity.Window.Attributes;
        attr.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
        Activity.Window.Attributes = attr;

        //Hide the ToolBar
        ftoolbar = (V7Toolbar)Activity.FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        ftoolbar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        //Load views for this Fragment
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MGradesView, null);
        return view;
    }
```